# Why do I get the warning "Expression implicitly coerced from 'xx?' to 'Any'"?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, swift5

Since swift5 I get a warning that confuses me a lot...

When I have  constraints in my views that should be modifiable it usually looks like this:

```
class myView: UIView {

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let descriptionLabel = UILabel()

    var titlePaddingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    func setupConstraints() {
        self.titlePaddingConstraint = self.titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.descriptionLabel.topAnchor, constant: -20)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.titlePaddingConstraint //warning here
        ])
    }
}
```

On the 4th last line XCode complains:

> Expression implicitly coerced from 'NSLayoutConstraint?' to 'Any'

To make it shut up I have to add the "bang operator (!)" to unwrap it. Why is that needed now? The `titlePaddingConstraint` is forced unwrapped at declaration. Isn't this supposed to avoid the unwrapping for that object completely?

Comment: Your code couldn't even compile.

Comment: Because I don't have an init and the labels are like that? Yes, but that's not the point of the question..

Comment: Your code doesn't compile for several reasons. `titlePaddingConstraint` is a `let` and can't be reassigned, `NSLayoutConstraint.activate` wants an array of constraint not only one

Comment: you are right. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `activate` method accepts an array of `NSLayoutContstraints` where you are making a mistake. Update your class as,

```
class MyView: UIView {

  let titleLabel = UILabel()
  let descriptionLabel = UILabel()

  var titlePaddingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

  func setupConstraints() {
    self.titlePaddingConstraint = self.titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.descriptionLabel.topAnchor, constant: -20)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.titlePaddingConstraint])
  }
}
```

Comment: This [] is not needed anymore.

Comment: Why? Are you saying `Swift` isn't type safe anymore?

Comment: Ups no.. I forgot that I wrote an extension method to avoid the brackets. My bad.